# Not able to print csv file received in $_FILES on ajax post

Tags: php

My AJAX call code:

```
    var myform = document.getElementById("fileUploadForm");
    var formData = new FormData(myform);

    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
             url: gSAHost+'/Csv/upload',
             data: formData,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             cache: false,
             timeout: 600000,
             success: function (data) {           
                  console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);               
             },
             error: function (e) {             
                 console.log("ERROR : ", e); 

             }
         });
```

My Code in the upload function of the Csv class file

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['email_file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
              $num = count($data);
              echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
              $row++;
              for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                   echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
              }
      }
      fclose($handle);
}
else{
    echo "<p>No CSV was found</p>";
}
```

On doing print_r of $_FILES['email_file']. I get the following output in Csv class file:

```
SUCCESS :  Array
(
    [name] => two.csv
    [type] => text/csv
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpUf7IZq
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 101
)
```

My code is entering the else part,

```
echo "<p>No CSV was found</p>";
```

Please guide, what am I doing wrong in

```
fopen($_FILES['email_file']['tmp_name'], "r")
```

Comment: What does `<?=print_r(is_readable($_FILES['email_file']['tmp_name']),true)?>` return? Did you try to move the file out of its temporary location before opening it? (BTW file_get_contents is much shorter there)

Comment: @Chris S. It is returning false, means not readable, so what I should be doing to make it readable. What adjustments to be made in path?

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345122/why-php-can-not-see-tmp-files - Check if that occurs in your case first.